# Neural networks only classifies to one class out of five

Tags: r, keras, neural-network, classification

I want to compare random forests with neural networks on a dataset that has only categorical inputs and a categorical output. The output has 5 classes, and the current neural net I fit only classifies to one class and gives the same probability for each class for all the data inputs. I'm not sure why I get the same classification for each datapoint. 
I used Keras through R.

```
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 25, activation = "relu", input_shape = 41) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.11) %>% 
  layer_dense(units =18, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.001) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 5, activation = "softmax")

model %>% compile(
  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer  =optimizer_sgd(lr=0.01),
  metrics=c('accuracy')
)

history <- model %>% fit(x_train, y_train, 
                         epochs =100,batch_size = 50,
                         validation_split = 0.2)

 model %>% predict(x_test)
```

this is the output I get. It classifies each training point to the class with the highest probability, which is the third column in the output.

```
> (predictions)
            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
  [1,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
  [2,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
  [3,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
  [4,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
  [5,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
  [6,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
  [7,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
  [8,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
  [9,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [10,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [11,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [12,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [13,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [14,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [15,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [16,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [17,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [18,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [19,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [20,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [21,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [22,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [23,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [24,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [25,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [26,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [27,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [28,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [29,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [30,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [31,] 0.2001473 0.1990314 0.3208318 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [32,] 0.2001473 0.1990314 0.3208318 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [33,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [34,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [35,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [36,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [37,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [38,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [39,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [40,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [41,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [42,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
 [43,] 0.2001473 0.1990315 0.3208320 0.1130381 0.1669514
```

but the actual test target looks like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 2 2 3 2
2 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3
3 3 3 3 2 5 4 5 5 4 5 4 5 4 5 4 5 5 5 4 5 4 5 4 5 4 5 4 5 4 4 4 4
5 4 4 4 5 4 4 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

This is what my model predicts for the test parget:

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: You may have been unlucky with relu (it sometimes goes to all zeroes, then what comes later will be always constant. Did you notice your training loss frozen?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Daniel Möller. The training loss actually keeps on decreasing, while the validation loss increases. The training loss stays higher than the validation loss. The validation ACCURACY starts at 0 or quickly goes to zero and then stays at zero. Would you recommend using another activation function than Relu? I have tried quite a few different activation functions, but none of them seem the help.

Comment: I think your data may be corrupted. Inspect `x_train`, `x_test`, `y_train` and `y_test` and make sure they all obey the rules (different values, all between 0 and 1).